# Python pytesseract extract number from various images

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract, text-extraction

I have various type of images like those:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you see, they are all kinda similar, however I do not manage to properly extract the number on them.

So far my code consists in the following:

```
    lower = np.array([250,200,90], dtype="uint8")
    upper = np.array([255,204,99], dtype="uint8")

    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    data = image_to_string(res, lang="eng", config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
    numbers = int(''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', data)))
```

I tried twearking the psm parameter 6,8 and 13 they all work for some of those examples, but none on all, and I have no idea how I could circumvent my problem.

Another solution proposed is:

```
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*2, h*2))
erd = cv2.erode(gry, None, iterations=1)
thr = cv2.threshold(erd, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
bnt = cv2.bitwise_not(thr)
```

However, on the first picture, bnt gives:

[image]

And then pytesseract sees 460..

Any idea please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach:

---

- 1. Upsample
- 2. [Erosion](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)
- 3. [Simple-thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)
- 4. [Bitwise-not](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html)

---

**Upsampling** is required for accurate recognition. Resizing two-times will make the image readable.

**Erosion** operation is a morphological operation helps to remove the boundary of the pixels. Erosion remove the strokes on the digit, make it easier to detect.

**Thresholding** (Binary and Inverse Binary) helps to reveal the features.

**Bitwise-not** is an arithmetic operation highly useful for extracting part of the image.

You can learn more methods simple reading from [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#rescaling)

---

| Erosion | Threshold | Bitwise-not |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

Update

---

The first image is easy to read, since it is not requiring any pre-processing technique. Please read [How to Improve Quality of Tesseract](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHdch.jpg):

```
1460
720
3250
3146
2681
1470
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img_lst = ["oqWjd.png", "YZDt1.png", "MUShJ.png", "kbK4m.png", "POIK2.png", "4W3R4.png"]

for i, img_nm in enumerate(img_lst):
    img = cv2.imread(img_nm)
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    (h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
    if i == 0:
        thr = gry
    else:
        gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w * 2, h * 2))
        erd = cv2.erode(gry, None, iterations=1)
        if i == len(img_lst)-1:
            thr = cv2.threshold(erd, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        else:
            thr = cv2.threshold(erd, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    bnt = cv2.bitwise_not(thr)
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(bnt, config="--psm 6 digits")
    print("".join([t for t in txt if t.isalnum()]))
    cv2.imshow("bnt", bnt)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If you want to display comma in the result, change `print("".join([t for t in txt if t.isalnum()]))` line to `print(txt)`.

Not that on the fourth image the threshold method changed from binary to inverse-binary. Binary thresholding is not working accurately on all images. Therefore you need to change.

Comment: I've added an example (first picture) cause with your method is based on the background and with the first picture it slashes the first 1. And I have in the pool of pictures I'm trying to extract the numbers several of them like this. Perhaps you have a solution that could work on this first picture and the rest.

Comment: It shouldn't slash any integer. These pre-processing methods are used for [improving-quality](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) Perhaps you should upgrade your tesseract version to latest?

Comment: I've updated with what I obtain with your solution on the first picture. Can you confirm it is the same for you?

Comment: Sure, here you can see the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/zMipMVv) of my output.

Comment: Maybe the `imwrite` part of the code may gave the error in your environment. I've updated my code, you can try running again.

Comment: I am not sure that you have noticed: I've added another picture since your first reply, with output 1460. It is different from other picture as a neat background color change occur in the middle of 1. And for me our code bland the 1 in the middle with the background

Comment: I've updated my answer. See the answer under Update